# Можно ли хранить "путь" в списках и словарях в переменной?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Большой JSON читается в переменную:

```
json_response = json.loads(request.text)
```

Есть пачка методов, которые делают различные проверки различных элементов этого JSON'а

```
def testfoo(self, json_response):
    assertEquals(json_response['element']['some array'][0]['message'], 'foo')


def testbar(self, json_response):
    assertEquals(json_response['other element']['fizz']['buzz'], 'bar')
```

Вопрос: а можно ли "путь" внутри объекта хранить в переменной и передавать в метод как аргумент? Что-то вроде этого:

```
def assertByPath(self, json_response, path, expected):
    assertEquals(path.get(json_response), expected)

def testfoo(self, json_response):
    foopath = path(['element']['some array'][0]['message'])
    assertByPath(json_response, path, 'foo')

def testbar(self, json_response):
    barpath = path(['other element']['fizz']['buzz'])
    assertByPath(json_response, path, 'bar')
```

Что-то похожее предоставляет [CSS Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

UPD: есть даже аналогичный [JSONSelect](http://jsonselect.org/#code). А как насчет решения, которое работает не только для json, а для любого сочетания вложенных списков и словарей?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Python: Change values in dict of nested dicts using items in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11918852/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно "путь" просто как список передавать:

```
import operator

def get_by_path(obj, *path):
    return reduce(operator.getitem, path, obj)
```

Пример:

```
>>> get_by_path(response, 'element', 'some array', 0, 'message')
'foo'
```

Достоинство: позволяет в качестве ключей произвольные типы использовать.

Легко другой синтаксис поддерживать, если необходимо. Например, чтобы не плодить сущности без необходимости, можно использовать подмножество языка, используемого [`jq` утилитой (если ограничиться json типами)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters).

Comment: Спасибо, я в итоге использовал первый вариант решения (список и `reduce`). До jq пока руки не дошли, но штука отличная.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, всегда можно навелосипедить что-то свое:

```
d = {
    "1": {2, 3},
    "2": {
        "3": "foo"
    },
    "3": {
        "3.1": {
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    }
}


def value_from_path(d, path):
    parts = path.split('/')
    value = d

    while parts:
        part = parts.pop(0)
        value = value[part]

    return value


print(d['2']['3'])
print(value_from_path(d, '2/3'))
print(value_from_path(d, '3/3.1'))
print(value_from_path(d, '3/3.1/foo'))
print(value_from_path(d, '3'))
```

Консоль:

```
foo
foo
{'foo': 'bar'}
bar
{'3.1': {'foo': 'bar'}}
```

Comment: Можно, но хочется более естественный синтаксис. В своем велосипеде надо будет писать грамотную обработку исключений и многое другое. Ну и кода в итоге останется столько же. А вообще, спасибо за proof-of-concept. ) Кстати, в таком варианте я бы избавился от `split` и передавал просто список: `['3', '3.1', 'foo']`

Comment: Питон же такой красивый язык, я искренне надеюсь, что в нём и это делается как-нибудь просто. [`import antigravity` и всё такое](https://xkcd.com/353/)

Comment: Навелосипедил аналог с «естественным синтаксисом», но перечитал коммент и передумал выкладывать :(

Comment: нужно **больше** велосипедов :)