# Как получит доступ к элементу в json

Tags: python

Есть json перекодированный в словарь.Как получит доступ к 'body'?так как нету идентификатора для него

```
{
    "response": [
        78,
        {
            "date": ***,
            "uid": ***,
            "title": " ... ",
            "read_state": 1,
            "out": 1,
            "mid": 84,
            "body": "Hello my friend"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: В тему: [Можно ли хранить "путь" в списках и словарях в переменной?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/501465/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Элементы списка можно получать по индексу:

```
print(data['response'][1]['body'])
```