# Python parse json: как обработать исключение, когда в словаре нет ключа?

Tags: python, json, словари

Пытаюсь разобрать json с глубокой вложенностью, до 10 элементов, как обработать исключение, когда в словаре нет ключа?

```
d = json.loads(file)
print(
d['date'],
d['тип'],
d['инн'],
d['кпп'],
d['огрн'],
d['имяПолное'],
d['имяКраткое'],
d['оснВидДеятельности']['код'],
d['оснВидДеятельности']['наим'],
d['свАдрес']['адресРФ']['кодАдрКладр']
```

)
Последнего элемента к примеру нет(может быть в другом файле), получаю ошибку:

```
d['свАдрес']['адресРФ']['кодАдрКлад']
 KeyError: 'кодАдрКлад'
```

Хотел написать обработчик, но че т не очень получилось, ошибка та же

```
def get_err(s):
try:
    return s
except:
    return ''
```

В принт все показываю для отладки, в идеале нужно собрать значения ключей в строку с разделителем ; для последующего импорта в бд

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `s = d['тип'] + ';' + d['свАдрес']['адресРФ']['кодАдрКладр']`. Если `d['свАдрес']['адресРФ']['кодАдрКладр']` отсутствует в словаре то `None` ну или пробел

Чтобы вернуть значение по ключу или `None`, можно использовать `d.get('тип')`.

Чтобы [вернуть значение по указанному пути, заданного списком вложенных ключей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/501465/23044):

```
from functools import reduce

def get_by_path(d, *path, default=None):
    try:
        return reduce(dict.__getitem__, path, d)
    except KeyError:
        return default
```

Пример: `get_by_path(d, 'оснВидДеятельности', 'код')` или:

```
s = ';'.join([get_by_path(d, *path, default=' ')
              for path in [['тип'], ['свАдрес', 'адресРФ', 'кодАдрКладр']]])
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам, простое решение)

Answer (score 3):

Перехватывать исключение нужно в момент когда вы обращаетесь к ключу т.е.:

```
try
    d['some_key']
except KeyError:
    return ''
```

Comment: А как например в функцию передать цепочку ключей? Я же не знаю какого именно ключа может не быть. Или каждое обращение к ключу в try..except оборачивать?

Comment: @ss_beer можно в try обернуть либо сразу целый кусок кода, либо просто вызов той функции, в которой вы ожидаете исключение. Но нужно понимать, что в этом случае вся часть обёрнутого кода, которая идёт после проблемной строчки, не будет выполнена.

Comment: Немного не то, смотрите, я хочу на выходе получить строку csv. делаю так s = d['тип'] + ';' + d['свАдрес']['адресРФ']['кодАдрКладр'] . Если d['свАдрес']['адресРФ']['кодАдрКладр']   отсутствует в словаре то None ну или пробел. И так обрабатывать каждый ключ, например тип тоже может не быть

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать как-то так:

```
d = json.loads(file)


class JsonNode(dict):

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    if key in self:
      item = super().__getitem__(key)
      if isinstance(item, dict):
        return JsonNode(item)
      else:
        return item
    else:
      return JsonNode()

  def __repr__(self):
    return str(dict(self)) if self else str(None)


d = JsonNode(d)
```

При обращении по несуществующему ключу возвращает пустой объект. Поддерживает произвольную вложенность, даже если после несуществующего ключа идёт ещё несколько подключей.

При выводе через print или преобразовании к строке, пустой объект отображается как None.

Писал на сорую руку, так что, возможно, что-то надо допилить и отладить, но в целом принцип такой.

Comment: Спасибо, крутое решение :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно не обрабатывать исключение, а установить дефолтное значение для несуществующего ключа:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = json.loads(file)

new_json = defaultdict(
    lambda x=None: 'Ключ не найден',
    d
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Я в итоге решил так, может кому пригодится:

```
def check_sl(d, k):
if k[0] in d.keys():
    try:
        if d[k[0]] is None:
            # print('1')
            return ' '
        else:
            if len(k) > 1:
                # print('2')
                return check_sl(d[k[0]],k[1:])
            else:
                # print('3', str(d[k[0]]))
                return str(d[k[0]])
    except:
        return ' '
else:
    return ' '

check_sl(d,['оснВидДеятельности','код'])
```

Передавать ключи списком.