# Возможно ли решить проблему с поиском элементов на Python'е

Tags: python

у меня есть функция которая принимает от 2 до бесконечности аргументов (ключей). Вся база данных состоит из словарей. Все переданные аргументы являются путем.

(`baza[ arg[0] ][ arg[1] ][ arg[2] ]` и так далее)

Можно ли реализовать такое? Если да, то как?

Comment: [`get_by_path(baza, *arg)`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/501665/23044)

Comment: @jfs а можно на 3 версии тоже самое?

Comment: Да, достаточно `from functools import reduce` добавить

Comment: @jfs да, сработало.Но если там нет элемента, то он дает мне KeyError, и я бы не хотел бы делать на try except.Можно по другому или всё таки придётся делать?

Comment: Это уже отдельный вопрос. Для примера, более сложного случая, нажмите на [ссылку](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11918852/4279)

Comment: @jfs я посмотрел эту ссылку, но там тоже практически все используют try except. я попытаюсь тогда уж сам что-то придумать оригинальное. Могу ли я вас потом позвать, что бы вы оценили этот код?