# Как получить значения словаря, используя *args?

Tags: python-3.x, словари

К примеру, есть функция `def get_value(dict, *args): ...`, принимающая словарь и последовательные строковые значения (которые должные выполнять роль ключей к словарю).

Есть словарь и вызов функции:

```
example = {'main': {'configs': {'conf_path': './config.cfg', ... }, ... }
get_value(example, 'main', 'configs', 'conf_path')
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Извините, не могу понять, почему get_value(example, 'configs', 'conf_path'), а не get_value(example, 'main', 'configs', 'conf_path')?

Comment: Что реализовать? Какие данные вы хотите получить?

Comment: @КириллМалышев, значения ключей (value).

Comment: @Anton, исправил.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли хранить "путь" в списках и словарях в переменной?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501465/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: @jcommander, кроме заголовка, там ещё есть ответ. Вообще-то мне тоже кажется, что именно принятый там ответ отвечает на твой вопрос. Если это не так, то дополни свой вопрос.