# Правильный способ проверить response бд

Tags: python, api, тестирование, pytest

Здравствуйте! Подскажите наилучший способ проверить значения словаря?

Делаю тест на pytest, в ходе которого отправляю к api запрос с некоторым набором данных и в ответе получаю словарь примерно вот такого вида:

`{'user': '1', 'objects': [{'id': '1', 'event': [{'type': 'something', 'timestamp': '1522991335319'}]}], 'reached': True}`

Значение ключей `user`, `id`, `type` и `reached` должны будут совпадать с теми значениями, что я отсылал в запросе, значение ключа `timestamp` меня не интересует.

Если делать проверку значения через assert напрямую, то проверка объектов с более глубокой вложенностью, например type выглядит в коде не очень:

```
assert response["objects"][0]["event"][0]["type"] == "something"
```

Как можно проверять значения подобного респонса более эффективно?

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265939/comparing-python-dictionaries-and-nested-dictionaries)

Comment: ключ type у вас обязан по указанному пути быть или не важно в каком месте, если значение правильное? Если путь в списке, можно вспомогательную функцию определить, чтобы значение достать: [Можно ли хранить "путь" в списках и словарях в переменной?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/501465/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно делаю кортежи expected и actual, и их уже сравниваю.

```
expected = ('john doe', '1111', 'something', True)
actual = (
    response["user"],
    response["objects"][0]["id"],
    response["objects"][0]["event"][0]["type"],
    response["reached"]
)
assert expected == actual
```

Запускать `pytest` с ключом `-v`, тогда он явно покажет какие элементы в кортежах не равны.