# Как индексировать словарь кортежем/списком?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Есть словарь словарей:

```
a = {'a': {'b': {'c': {}}, 'd': {'e': {}}}}
```

И есть список/кортеж:

```
f = ('a', 'b', 'c')  #or ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Как можно реализовать с помощью того же кортежа следующее индексирование:

```
a['a']['b']['c'] = 'here' 
print(a['a']['b']['c'] )  # -> 'here'
```

PS То есть мы не знаем, что в словаре и что в кортеже. Но мы точно знаем, что в кортеже точно есть путь к нужному нам значению. И нужно, чтобы можно было изменить тот самый словарь (а именно - значение).

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Можно ли хранить "путь" в списках и словарях в переменной?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/501465/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас есть вложенный словарь:

```
nested_dict = {'a': {'b': {'c': {}}, 'd': {'e': {}}}}
```

И соответствующий путь:

```
path = 'a', 'b', 'c'
```

То присваивание можно реализовать как:

```
from functools import reduce

# nested_dict['a']['b']['c'] = 'here' 
*keys, newkey = path
reduce(dict.__getitem__, keys, nested_dict)[newkey] = 'here'
```

См. [Change values in dict of nested dicts using items in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11918852/4279)

Аналогично чтение значения по пути:

```
# print(nested_dict['a']['b']['c'] ) # -> 'here'
print(reduce(dict.__getitem__, path, nested_dict))  # -> here
```

См. [Можно ли хранить "путь" в списках и словарях в переменной?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/501465/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Получение значения:

```
from functools import reduce

value = reduce(lambda c, k: c[k], f, a)
```

С присваиванием сложнее. Решение в лоб:

```
c = a
for n, k in enumerate(f, start=1):
    if n == len(f):
        c[k] = 'here'
    else:
        c = c[k]
```

Ну или можно не изобретать велосипед и использовать [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/), например.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> a = {'a': {'b': {'c': {}}, 'd': {'e': {}}}}
>>> f = ('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> reduce(lambda c,k: c[k], f[:-1], a)[f[-1]]='here'
>>> a
{'a': {'b': {'c': 'here'}, 'd': {'e': {}}}}
```