# Работа с "глубокими" словарями в Python 3.6.*

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, словари

Столкнулся с проблемой поиска по "глубокому" словарю (много вложенных друг в друга словарей). Словарь получается из .json файла и содержит в себе вложенные словари схожей структуры. У меня задача получить все значения определенных полей словарей на одном из нижних уровней, сейчас делаю рекурсивно, но возможно кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой, и есть какие-нибудь модули по типу beautifulsoup для решения подобных задач.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как индексировать словарь кортежем/списком — Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/819438/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне для работы с словарями понравился модуль [dpath](https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python):

```
# pip install dpath
import dpath.util

x = {
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "3": 2,
            "43": 30,
            "c": [],
            "d": ['red', 'buggy', 'bumpers'],
        }
    }
}
```

#### Получение значения:

```
print(dpath.util.get(x, 'a/b/d'))   # ['red', 'buggy', 'bumpers']
print(dpath.util.get(x, 'a/b/d/0'))  # red
print(dpath.util.get(x, 'a/b/d/1'))  # buggy
print(dpath.util.get(x, 'a/b/43'))   # 30
print()
```

#### Получение списка значений:

```
print(dpath.util.values(x, "**/43"))   # [30]
print(dpath.util.values(x, "**/d/1"))  # [buggy]
print()
```

#### Поиск:

```
print(dpath.util.search(x, "**/43"))  # {'a': {'b': {'43': 30}}}
print(list(dpath.util.search(x, "**/43", yielded=True)))  # [('a/b/43', 30)]
print()
```

#### Поиск с фильтрацией:

```
def afilter(x):
    return str(x).isdecimal()


result = dpath.util.search(x, '**', afilter=afilter)
print(result)  # {'a': {'b': {'3': 2, '43': 30}}}

# Фильтрация через лябмды:
result = dpath.util.search(x, '**', afilter=lambda x: str(x).isdecimal())
print(result)  # {'a': {'b': {'3': 2, '43': 30}}}

result = list(dpath.util.search(x, '**', yielded=True, afilter=afilter))
print(result)  # [('a/b/3', 2), ('a/b/43', 30)]
```

---

[Код из примера](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/15dbd10cead9a82905627347da5802cdd0fb2aae/dpath__examples__search_filter__dict_json/main.py)

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ.